# Replace text in Google Sheet depending on the value of another column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Been struggling to find a way to get this done faster, at the moment I am using mailmerg on linux to create multiple versions of the text and manually posting them in my sheet..
Is how could I update lets the message column's placeholder value with column ID's value.

| ID | Message |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | sample {ID} not avaliable |
| 4 | sample {ID} not avaliable |

Comment: Hi! It's really hard to understand the problem with this information only. Do you want to achieve it via Google Apps Script, Formula? Please consider having a look at the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and sharing a copy of your file, so folks can help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Replace {ID} with value from column1

```
function replaceId() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//change sheet name
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getDisplayValues();
  let a = vs.map(r => {
    r[1] = r[1].replace('{ID}', r[0]);//returns a new string
    return [r[1]];
  });
  sh.getRange(2, 2, a.length, 1).setValues(a);
}
```

[String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Before:

| ID | Message |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | sample {ID} not avaliable |
| 4 | sample {ID} not avaliable |

After:

| ID | Message |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | sample 3 not avaliable |
| 4 | sample 4 not avaliable |

Comment: Hi @Cooper, I have added another 2 lines to get it to work for multiple replacements in the message text, any way this can be cleaned up?
`function replaceId() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("codetest");//change sheet name
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getDisplayValues();
  let a = vs.map(r => {
    r[1] = r[1].replace('{ID}', r[0]);//returns a new string
    return [r[1]];
    r[2] = r[2].replace ('{ID}' , r[0]);
    return [r[2]];
  });
  sh.getRange(2, 2, a.length, 1).setValues(a);
}`

Comment: One problem is that there is no r[2] in the source range and I wouldn't have thought you can do two returns like that.